# CORS error using fetch API - React create app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch-api

I'm consuming an API using fetch but i'm getting CORS error. 
I tried multiples headers, but I'm not understading what's the problem.

I'm not the owner of the API, so I couldn't change it, but checking the response it's returning `access-control-allow-origin`.

Following is my request method:

```
export const execPOST = (url, body) => {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  });
};
```

The response is:

```
Request URL: http://api
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: ip
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Isn't this response above enough to allow my request?

console error:

> OPTIONS `http://api` net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>       Access to fetch at `'http://api'` from origin `'http://localhost:3000'` has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

I got this working (meanwhile I develop) using `"https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"`, but I don't think that I should use this for production enviroment.

I found a lot of material about this problem, but nothing that worked besides implements a backend to make the request or use something else as a proxy to make the request and so on...

Comment: What makes you say you are getting a CORS error?... Apparently the error is because the endpoint you are targeting does not allow the method. Can you try using a rest client to debug?

Comment: I edited my question adding chrome console log. Using postman or soapui it works

Comment: The API isn't responding to OPTIONS requests (otherwise known as preflights.) To avoid preflights, do not set custom headers.

Comment: ...and use GET request only... I believe when you are sending `body` there is no way to user GET

Comment: POST can be sent without a preflight, if the content-type is left at default, no additional headers are set, and with-credentials is not used. Simply remove `headers` and send your data as a paramstring instead of json. If the server doesn't support that, you'll have to use your own server to send the request.

Comment: @KevinB, I saw this option looking for the solution. The problem is that the endpoint expects the content-type to be an `application/json`

Comment: I think you're just out of luck then.

Comment: Setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in your request makes no sense...this is a header the server sets to indicate whether you are allowed to access the URL via a cross-domain request or not. It's an essential part of CORS security. If the requestor could set the header to whatever they wanted then clearly it would not provide any security

Comment: And if the server doesn't allow CORS requests from your domain then there is not much you do about it, except ask the maintainers of the server if they will amend their code to allow it. Or, some bigger providers have a process where you can register your site as a trusted client who is then allowed to make cross-domain requests to that API

Answer (score 9):

Update code as given below (use 'mode' with the value 'no-cors' ):

For more details follow the link => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
export const execPOST = (url: string, body: any) => {
  return fetch(url, {
    mode: 'no-cors',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  });
};
```

Comment: no, it is not correct, no-cors value cannot work simultaneously with 'application/json' https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: @Panos Although the documentation does say that, I am able to send json data with `no-cors` on Google Chrome. Weirdly, if I set mode to `cors`, it complains about CORS issue

Answer (score 4):

CORS headers are set by the API to protect users from malicious code making requests to sites on their behalf.

This means that you cannot enable or disable it from the client side as the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is a server side only header.

If you don't have access to the API to change the headers then you won't be able to use the API from the client side.

In production you would have to create your own API that will handle the requests to the API you are trying to contact.

Comment: `This means that you cannot disable it from the client side`  Can I suggest amending this line to say "enable or disable".

Comment: `If you don't have access to the API to change the headers then you won't be able to use the api.` This isn't quite true; CORS only applies to browser requests.  A proxying API endpoint on the hosting server isn't bound by CORS rules.

Comment: Thanks @Amy, I've updated it to mention the client side

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Like I posted in my question, the server is already returning "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". Isn't this enough to client-side request to work?

Comment: @VictorBello server answers "I don't understand OPTIONS request that your browser sent to me to perform CORS check". It does not matter if there are `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header or not if status is not 200 OK

Comment: From the error message it's likely that the server hasn't implemented a response to the preflight `OPTIONS` request, meaning that you get method not allowed and a CORS error. Either way it is not something you can fix if you can't make changes to the server. You will have to implement a backend solution to proxy the requests to the API.